# Problem updating to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, php

I was trying to update my server from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 with the command ‘‘do-release-upgrade’’ but after the update is done, I can’t access my wordpress website. It gives errors either ‘‘error establishing database connection’’ or 500 internal server error’'. When I was starting the update, I’m getting a lot of ‘‘no candidate ver’’ lines which I think might be related to the site not working after the update is done.

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sJu2.jpg

Comment: There are a number of differences between Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 when it comes to MySQL and PHP. Have you confirmed that the MySQL database is still operational? If it is, then recovery will not be too complicated. If the database needs to be rebuilt, then recovery may be more involved. Is WordPress also up to date? Older versions (in the early 5.x and older) releases will not work properly on 22.04 because the newer Ubuntu uses PHP 8.0 rather than the 7.x release.

Comment: Yes, Wordpress is up to date, 6.0.2. After I noticed that it is not working. I just rolled back to my backup. I also tried restarting mysql, apache, etc. but it didn't work. I'm actually not sure what should I check to find the problem and then solve it.